# How to set default encoding for non UTF encoded documents system wide?

Tags: gedit, encoding

The title says pretty much most of it - I have some windows txt files, and most of them are Bulgarian with encoding windows-1251. When I open them (sublime, gedit, desktop generated icons) the files are with windows-1252 (western Europe) I can manually select the file encoding, but it get pretty much tiresome after some time.

So, how to set default encoding for non UTF encoded documents?

Answer (score 4):

Just set the encoding in a terminal by entering this line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings auto-detected "['UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', 'CURRENT', 'ISO-8859-15', 'UTF-16']"
```

Comment: This saved my day, another tip is the order of encoding is important to mark the priority.

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to create a script that invokes gedit with the `--encoding` option, as in Superuser question [Gedit - how to set default encoding opening?](https://superuser.com/questions/323515/gedit-how-to-set-default-encoding-opening)

Comment: This will solve my issue with gedit, but not with the other 15 programs. BTW, Kate works as expected out of the box :)